# Generating QR Barcode using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext, barcode, vb.net-2010

I have an array of values say

```
arr(0)="Sam"
arr(1)="1452"
arr(2)="NY"
```

I want to generate a QR barcode with these values. We are using ITextSharp. Any help will be appreciated. Iam using vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples how to create barcodes with iText:

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=297 (the last one is a QR barcode)

The datails of the API is here:

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeQRCode.html

Please note that even though these links refer to the Java version of iText, the names in iTextSharp should be pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks alexis. How about decoding

Comment: iText generates QR barcodes as images, but doesn't provide the functionality to "read" these images if that's what you mean by "decoding". You'll need some QR code reader lib for that.

Comment: I would if I knew any. Google is your friend!

Comment: Is not there any examples about itext7 ?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon I can not find how to set dimension like in itext5 such as new BarcodeQRCode(data, dimension, dimension, null);