# Adding a QRCODE to a document uploaded to document library through EventReceiver (iTextSharp, SharePoint, and QRCoder)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, itext

I'm trying to stamp a QRCode on PDF documents when a user uploads them to a document library and checks it in with metadata (A new field called "DocumentCode").

From what I know, I'll have to check it out, read the DocumentCode value from the document checked out, generate a QRCode using "QRCODER" from NuGet, use PDFStamper to stamp it on the first page using iTextSharp.

I'm giving up on trying to resolve it without asking for help, so I'm here to ask for help.

This is the code I wrote:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using QRCoder;

namespace WFA.CodeTestReceiver
{

    public class CodeTestReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

        public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPFile UploadedFile = properties.ListItem.File;
                byte[] FileContent = UploadedFile.OpenBinary();
                QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGen = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGen.CreateQrCode(properties.ListItem["DocumentCode"].ToString(), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q, true, false);
                BitmapByteQRCode qrBitmap = new BitmapByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
                byte[] qrBytes = qrBitmap.GetGraphic(6);
                byte[] NewFile;

                MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(qrBytes);

                using (Stream iPDF = new MemoryStream(FileContent))
                using (Stream iIMG = new MemoryStream(qrBytes))
                using (Stream oPDF = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var reader = new PdfReader(iPDF);
                    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, oPDF);
                    var PDC = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                    var pSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

                    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(iIMG);
                    Point P = new Point(0, 0);
                    P.X = 50;
                    P.Y = 700;
                    int Y = (int)(pSize.Height - P.Y);
                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 300);
                    PDC.AddImage(image);
                    oPDF.CopyTo(MS);
                    NewFile = MS.ToArray();
                    stamper.Close();
                }
                SPFile sFile = web.Folders["CodeTest"].Files.Add(properties.ListItem.File.Name, NewFile, true);

            }
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        }


        public override void ItemCheckedIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPFile UploadedFile = properties.ListItem.File;
                byte[] FileContent = UploadedFile.OpenBinary();
                QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGen = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGen.CreateQrCode(properties.ListItem["DocumentCode"].ToString(), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q, true, false);
                BitmapByteQRCode qrBitmap = new BitmapByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
                byte[] qrBytes = qrBitmap.GetGraphic(6);
                byte[] NewFile;

                MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(qrBytes);

                using (Stream iPDF = new MemoryStream(FileContent))
                using (Stream iIMG = new MemoryStream(qrBytes))
                using (Stream oPDF = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var reader = new PdfReader(iPDF);
                    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, oPDF);
                    var PDC = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                    var pSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

                    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(iIMG);
                    Point P = new Point(0, 0);
                    P.X = 50;
                    P.Y = 700;
                    int Y = (int)(pSize.Height - P.Y);
                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 300);
                    PDC.AddImage(image);
                    oPDF.CopyTo(MS);
                    NewFile = MS.ToArray();
                    stamper.Close();
                }
                SPFile sFile = web.Folders["CodeTest"].Files.Add(properties.ListItem.File.Name, NewFile, true);

            }
            base.ItemCheckedIn(properties);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that iText also can generate barcodes, including QR codes, as native iText objects?

Comment: No, that's new to me.
Any reference or links?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10507028/766786

Comment: At which point do you have problems / where do you need help exactly? For the QRCoder parts I may help you, because I have written that library...